# How to add list of objects when sending formData to a spring server with ajax

Tags: java, ajax, spring, form-data

The objs value is null in the code written as below. I tried various things, but as a result objs is null. How to add list of objects in FormData??

When checking the payload on the Network tab, objs is as follows.

```
obj[0]: {"name":"n1", "age":10}
obj[1]: {"name":"n2", "age":20}
```

Also, the value of objs is as follows when i check from `HttpServletRequest request` and `request.getParameterMap()`.

```
["{"name":"n1", "age":10}", "{"name":"n2", "age":20}"]
```

#### javascript

```
$('#submit-button').click(
      function () {
        var objs = [{"name":"n1", "age":10}, {"name":"n2", "age":20}];
      
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("title", $('#title').val());
        formData.append("summary", $('#summary').val());
        formData.append("content", $('#content').val());
        for (var i=0; i < objs.length; i++) {
          formData.append("objs[" + i + "]", JSON.stringify(objs[i])); //this is not working
          //formData.append("objs", objs[i]); //this is not working
          //formData.append("objs[" + i + "].name", objs[i].name); //this is not working
        }

        $.ajax({
          url: "/example",
          type: "POST",
          data: formData,
          enctype: "multipart/form-data",
          contentType: false,
          processData: false
        });
      }
    )
```

#### DTO in java spring

```
public record ExampleRequest(
        @NotBlank
        String title,
        @NotBlank
        String summary,
        @NotBlank
        String content,
        @NotNull
        List<OBJ> objs,
){}
```

```
public record OBJ(
    String name,
    Integer age
) {}
```

#### Controller

```
    @PostMapping("/example")
    public String example(
            @Validated @ModelAttribute ExampleRequest exampleRequest, //request.objs is null...
            BindingResult bindingResult
    ) {}
```

I want `var objs = [{"name":"n1", "age":10}, {"name":"n2", "age":20}];` in javascript to be `List<OBJ>` in spring. Help me...

Answer (score 0):

Your request on your Spring backend is expecting a List of "OBJ". Instead, you are giving multiple "OBJ" objects separately which would construct this:

- key: "objs[0]", value: "{"name":"n1", "age":10}
- key: "objs[1]", value: "{"name":"n2", "age":20}

Instead, you should be doing:

```
formData.append("objs", JSON.stringify(objs));
```

Which will give you what you want:

- key: "objs", value: "[{"name":"n1", "age":10}, {"name":"n2", "age":20}];"

Spring will then know that this is a List of "OBJ" when it is mapping the data in the params to the expected object.

Additionally, you are using **multipart/form-data** for *enctype*, which is intended for file-based requests (like a file upload). This should be "application/json" instead.

Comment: thanks for your comment. as you said, I was able to get key, value.
`key: "objs", value: "[{"name":"n1", "age":10}, {"name":"n2", "age":20}];"`
but objs still has a null value on the controller.

Comment: I just noticed this now - you are using multipart/form-data is your main issue. You should not be using that. multipart/form-data is for file-based requests (like an upload). You should be using application/json.